# crash reporter offline for android device offline

Tags: java, android, kotlin, crash, offline

I have a device android, example [friendly arm](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/tiny210) and this is offline. I need to see crashes in this device. for example, crash save in sd card.
can I use firebase crashlytics offline and save in file? or use other library. I need a full report, for example ram, storage, line crash, and etc.

Comment: Does this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58109924/945808) help? @rasoul-miri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you can implement such mechanism to track the crash logs yourself.
check out the following piece of code to handle within Application class:

```
import android.app.Application

class TestApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val exceptionHandler = SimpleExceptionHandler()
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler)
    }
}


class SimpleExceptionHandler : Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    override fun uncaughtException(thread: Thread, exc: Throwable) {
        // Log your exception here to files, database, etc together with the device status like RAM, processes, network condition that the crash point 
    }
}
```

You can choose the way to store your information like text file, database, etc

Comment: I need a library